# Flutter TabBar Margin/padding between label

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 `TabBar`s and I want to place the label to the left of the categories.

The `TabBar` I want:

[image]

My `TabBar`:

[image]

My code:

```
       // BOTTOM
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
            child: TabBar(
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              labelStyle: poppins.copyWith(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: bold,
              ),
              unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff585861),
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,

              // TABS
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: 'Following',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Trending',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Search',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer below code and try to add  `isScrollable: true,` inside `TabBar()` widget

Refer Tabbar [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs)

Refer isScrollable [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/isScrollable.html)

```
   bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
            child: TabBar(
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              isScrollable: true,// add this property
              unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff585861),
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,

              // TABS
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: 'Following',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Trending',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Search',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: you guys are awesome thanks.

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to find the solution to this.

Just by adding **`isScrollable: true`** parameter to **`TabBar()`** all tabs shrink to one side.

Without setting **`isScrollable: true`** all tabs items were taking all the space they have in the given widget.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the **labelPadding** property

```
labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bottom:  PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
            child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              labelColor: Colors.white,
              labelStyle: poppins.copyWith(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: bold,
              ),
              unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff585861),
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,

              // TABS
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: 'Following',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Trending',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Search',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```